# iterating over multidimensional numpy array and skipping rows

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I am trying to iterate over a multidimensional numpy array while trying to solve one of the Project Euler problems. The problem requires finding the largest product of four adjacent numbers in a 20x20 grid. For now, I am just testing to see if my code is grabbing four adjacent numbers, going left to right horizontally:

```
arr1 = np.array([[8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15, 0, 40, 0, 75, 4, 5, 7, 78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91, 8], 
                 [49, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 17, 40, 98, 43, 69, 48, 4, 56, 62, 0],
                [81, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 40, 67, 53, 88, 30, 3, 49, 13, 36, 65]])


 for row in arr1:
    checklist = []
    m = 0
    n = 4
    while n <= 20:
        checklist.append(row[m:n])

        m += 1
        n += 1

print(checklist)
```

The returned checklist is:

```
[array([81, 49, 31, 73]), array([49, 31, 73, 55]), array([31, 73, 55, 79]), array([73, 55, 79, 14]), array([55, 79, 14, 29]), array([79, 14, 29, 93]), array([14, 29, 93, 71]), array([29, 93, 71, 40]), array([93, 71, 40, 67]), array([71, 40, 67, 53]), array([40, 67, 53, 88]), array([67, 53, 88, 30]), array([53, 88, 30,  3]), array([88, 30,  3, 49]), array([30,  3, 49, 13]), array([ 3, 49, 13, 36]), array([49, 13, 36, 65])]
```

This is what I was looking for, but it's only grabbing the last row of the array. Why are the first two rows being skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `checklist` variable inside the `for` loop. That's why in each iteration of `for` loop, `checklist` variable is being reset to `[ ]`. Hence it is keeping data only of the last iteration of for loop i.e. last row of `arr1`.

You should declare `checklist` above the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `checklist` variable is being reset inside the for loop on each iteration. Move the declaration above the for loop.